# Element ID not being collected by Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, clicklistener

I use tag manager's "click listener" to collect clicks on a website form, which I then analyse in the "events" section of google analytics. This all seems to be working fine, apart from with an important button that's part of the page template...

If you check out https://lptent.worldsecuresystems.com/pop-up-gazebos.html and click "Configure this Gazebo" you'll see a blue button appear in the header of the form which reads "chat to an expert". This is the button/element we are struggling with.

Any help or advice on tracking clicks on this element would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `href="javascript:void(0);"` is preventing the event from bubbling up through the DOM.

Try instead adding a dataLayer.push({}); in your click function:

```
jQuery("a.lp_box").click(function(){
    var rel = jQuery(this).attr("rel"),
       grel = rel.split("#")[1];
        jQuery("#"+grel).css("top", "60px" ).fadeIn(500);
        dataLayer.push({'event': 'chatClick'});
        bg_lightbox();
});
```

And then create your event in GTM using {{event}} equals chatClick as your rule for that event.

Comment: Hi @blexy and thanks for the help. The code has been added and I've added a rule to my tag that was already collecting the other clicks' element IDs. The rule is {{event}} equals chatClick. I can't see anything in analytics yet - is there anything else I need to do or is it a case of waiting?..

Comment: I see the event getting pushed into the `dataLayer`, and I see two events firing when I click on the 'chat to an expert' link, however the event doesn't have an action (which is a mandatory parameter), and that's why it's not getting to GA. I would look into why it's firing twice, too.

Comment: I've just had another go at setting this up. I created a Universal Analytics tag with Category "Chat Button Clicks On Quote Form" and Action {{element id}}. The rule should fire the tag when {{url}} contains lptent.worldsecuresystems.com/quote-form.html and the {{event}} equals chatClick. It still looks like I'm doing something wrong as nothing is coming through to analytics. Thanks for your patience @Blexy!

Comment: So when I use the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna), I see the event action as `undefined`. Looking into more, GTM attaches itself to the innermost element, so in your case, the <img> tag within the <a> tag, which doesn't have an id, hence the `undefined`. What you could do is just provide a static value for the event action e.g. Click, or put an id on the image tag to use {{element id}}. You can also remove the {{url}} contain lptent.worldsecuresystems.com/quote-form.html.

Comment: Looks like this is now working @Blexy. Thanks for persevering with me, I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm having a problem with this in Drupal, my ticket hasn't been answered on drupal stack exchange. I'm finding GTM a bit of a mission. I can't seem to generate/get/see element id